# sleep in a bash script

Tags: bash, sleep

I experience a weird problem; I have a bash script that runs as wwwrun, triggered by button in a browser. Inside the script there is a sleep but I after many trials I realize that if I do a sleep of few seconds/minute everything is ok, while with more than 5 minutes the script stops the execution.. any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a script timeout setting in your php.ini which is being triggered, try extending that.

max_execution_time is the item you want top change in the php.ini

Comment: I modified that field to a very big value but I still see that the job is changing PID every 5 minutes (and of course the script is not doing what it was foreseen due to this issue)

Comment: did you restart the webserver and your php runner?

Comment: If my answer helped solve would you mind marking it as the answer then?